# Storybook: The requested module XXX does not provide an export named keys

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, storybook

I am using React & Vite, And I am trying to integrate Storybook.
When I run command: `"storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006"`

I could see the Storybook running properly.

When I run command:   `"build-storybook": "storybook build"`, I encounter import issue, the error message:

```
=> Failed to build the preview
RollupError: "keys" is not exported by "../external-package/dist/index.js", imported by "src/components/componentA.tsx".
```

**This import does not works**

```
import { keys } from 'external-package';
```

**This import works:**

```
import keys  from 'external-package/src/keys';
import * as resources from 'external-package/src/keys';
Use as  resources.keys
```

Does anyone has any pointer how to fix this issue?

Here is the compilerOptions I have in general, I did not add any additional configuration in viteFinal.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
```

Comment: Can you share the name of the package you are using? If not, then the `package.json` file of that external package and the main entrypoint file! tsconfig does not have any effect on generated bundle as it is used only for type checking and internally Storybook uses `babel-loader` for TypeScript compilation.